# OptaPlanner ShadowVariable error: not a valid planning entity

Tags: optaplanner

I am new in OptaPlanner, and currently I was confused by it's ShadowVariable annotation.

Below are simple Spring Boot codes I modified from OptaPlanner Quick Start of TimeTable example.

I made Room as PlanningEntity, and added a field named lessons with @InverseRelationShadowVariable annotated, but when I run these codes, it throws errors: **not a valid planning entity** , I searched many documents but still no solutions.

1. Lesson.java

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Lesson {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String subject;
    private String teacher;
    private String studentGroup;

    @PlanningVariable
    private Timeslot timeslot;
    @PlanningVariable
    private Room room;

    // No-arg constructor required for OptaPlanner
    public Lesson() {
    }

    public Lesson(long id, String subject, String teacher, String studentGroup) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.studentGroup = studentGroup;
    }

    public Lesson(long id, String subject, String teacher, String studentGroup, Timeslot timeslot, Room room) {
        this(id, subject, teacher, studentGroup);
        this.timeslot = timeslot;
        this.room = room;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return subject + "(" + id + ")";
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ************************************************************************

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public String getStudentGroup() {
        return studentGroup;
    }

    public Timeslot getTimeslot() {
        return timeslot;
    }

    public void setTimeslot(Timeslot timeslot) {
        this.timeslot = timeslot;
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

}
```

2. Room.java

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Room {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "room")
    private List<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<>();

    public Integer getLessonCount() {
        log.info("size: {}", lessonList.size());
        return this.lessonList.size();
    }

    public Room() {
    }

    public Room(String name) {
        this.name = name.trim();
    }

    public Room(long id, String name) {
        this(name);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ************************************************************************


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name.trim();
    }

}
```

3.TimeTable.java

```
@PlanningSolution
public class TimeTable {

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider
    private List<Timeslot> timeslotList;
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider
    private List<Room> roomList;
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Lesson> lessonList;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    // No-arg constructor required for OptaPlanner
    public TimeTable() {
    }

    public TimeTable(List<Timeslot> timeslotList, List<Room> roomList, List<Lesson> lessonList) {
        this.timeslotList = timeslotList;
        this.roomList = roomList;
        this.lessonList = lessonList;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ************************************************************************

    public List<Timeslot> getTimeslotList() {
        return timeslotList;
    }

    public List<Room> getRoomList() {
        return roomList;
    }

    public List<Lesson> getLessonList() {
        return lessonList;
    }

    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return score;
    }

}
```

4.SolverFactory

```
        SolverFactory<TimeTable> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                .withSolutionClass(TimeTable.class)
                .withEntityClasses(Lesson.class)
                .withEntityClasses(Room.class)
                .withConstraintProviderClass(TimeTableConstraintProvider.class)
                // The solver runs only for 5 seconds on this small dataset.
                // It's recommended to run for at least 5 minutes ("5m") otherwise.
                .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

```
2023-08-06 16:48:08,819 ERROR [http-nio-8090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log(175): Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Room) has an @InverseRelationShadowVariable annotated property (lessons) with a sourceClass (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson) which is not a valid planning entity.
Maybe check the annotations of the class (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson).
Maybe add the class (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson) among planning entities in the solver configuration.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Room) has an @InverseRelationShadowVariable annotated property (lessons) with a sourceClass (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson) which is not a valid planning entity.
Maybe check the annotations of the class (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson).
Maybe add the class (class com.example.optatest.timeTabling.entity.Lesson) among planning entities in the solver configuration.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.InverseRelationShadowVariableDescriptor.linkShadowSources(InverseRelationShadowVariableDescriptor.java:77) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.InverseRelationShadowVariableDescriptor.linkVariableDescriptors(InverseRelationShadowVariableDescriptor.java:47) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.entity.descriptor.EntityDescriptor.linkVariableDescriptors(EntityDescriptor.java:413) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.afterAnnotationsProcessed(SolutionDescriptor.java:482) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolutionDescriptor.java:108) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolutionDescriptor(DefaultSolverFactory.java:147) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.<init>(DefaultSolverFactory.java:69) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.create(SolverFactory.java:106) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.41.0.Final.jar:9.41.0.Final]
    at com.example.optatest.controller.Test04Controller.test04(Test04Controller.java:27) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Please support: what should i do that i can make the field lessons be changed following the field room of Lesson.java ?  Very thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to Anna Dupliak from OptaPlanner development.

the answer to my question is to add both Room.class and Lesson.class into .withEntityClasses(Lesson.class, Room.class).

the Config will be like as below:

```
        SolverFactory<TimeTable> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
            .withSolutionClass(TimeTable.class)
            .withEntityClasses(Lesson.class, Room.class)
            .withConstraintProviderClass(TimeTableConstraintProvider.class)
            .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```